# Is there a fast way to convert a n x m matrix to a obj file?

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, wavefront, heightmap

I am following [this tutorial (OpenGL 3.3)](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org).

I have a set of data collecting the average height of 5 x 5 meters cells of terrain, i.e. a sort of height map. I would like to render the overall terrain, so, following the tutorial (see [Tutorial 7](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905152310/http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-7-model-loading/)), I would need to convert the height map to an obj., and this led to this question.

Any different smarter way to render the height map is welcome!

PS: just for clarity this is a quote of the height map file:

```
ncols         1330
nrows         1165
xllcorner     1750245
yllcorner     5126883
cellsize      5
NODATA_value  -9999
1307.667 1309.289 1312.596 1316.905 1322.135 1327.314 1332.05 1337.79 1344.144      1351.303 1356.64 1359.371 1361.858 1367.082 1375.733 1385.611 1394.988 1401.936 1406.447 1410.402 1415.272 1419.87 1423.265 1426.903 1430.771 1434.331 1436.966 
......
```

Comment: Is the obj file the intermediate file produced by the compiler?

Comment: No, it is where the object model is saved, a simple Wavefront file.

Comment: What do you mean fast? Fast comparing to what?

Comment: Maybe an existing tool for the conversion, or a completely different and more efficient way to render the height map in OpenGL.

Comment: @alain have you tried anything? for example creating mesh from heightmap? like here: http://www.mbsoftworks.sk/index.php?page=tutorials&series=1&tutorial=24